# Is it possible to zoom an image in page view controller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I created a page view controller that load an array of images.Now i want to zoom image.Is it possible to do without using UIscrollView controller? If possible can any one tell me how it is?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Mr.Neeku.,I want to Zoom an image  using pinch gesture recogniser.,Can you Help me?

Comment: 1. I'm not a "Mr.". 2. No one here can help you with the little information you've provided. Please see the [help](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to learn how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your view controller add a `UIScrollView` and within that the `UIImageView` and hook both of these up using IBOutlets.

Then in your .h file:

Implement the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`

In the .m file

```
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.75; //The minimum zoom scale (currently .75x the image size)
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=4.0; //Maximum zoom (currently 4x image size)
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Also implement the delegate method:

```
    - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        return self.imageView; //Needs to be the same as the outlet you created in the .h file
    }
```